# Is there a way to fast create different screen layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

Working with Android Studio and having to deal with several screen sizes made me wonder, if there was **a way to create the different layout files for each size faster than the common way**.

Example : I have created a new project, there is my MainActivity and its layout activity_main.xml (the default for handsets devices), I will fill my layout and then copy it in two other directories :

res/layout-sw600dp in order to support the devices from 7" to 10"

res/layout-sw720dp for devices bigger than 10"

Then I will fill those layouts also, no problem. But now imagine a project with a huge number of classes, the time spent to every time add those different layouts is consequent, especially if the views inside the layouts are not identical.

I searched a lot about this on different websites, I found out that using wrap content and match parent for the height and width attributes of the layout or stock string values of sizes in dimens.xml  is a good practice, and a lot of other good advises about optimizations, but it seems that the one and only way to create different layouts for different screen sizes is the one I wrote previously.

So, does someone has found / knows a faster way to deal with those screen sizes ?

I'm looking to all solutions that can help in this way : software tool, modification of some files inside android studio, snippets of code, online templates editor... 
Or a simple "no, this is not possible to do another way" would be fine too, if you're absolutely sure of it based on your experience / knowledge.

**---- EDIT ----**

I discovered a nice way to create rapidly other layouts, this option is the "Orientation for Preview" inside the layout editor of Android Studio.
From there, you can directly and rapidly create landscapes and other sizes layouts based on the actual one. I'm sharing how to do in pics in case it could help someone :

[image: Select Orientation for Preview and create the wanted layout]

[image: Add the desired qualifiers and build the layout rapidly]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don’t understand about **faster** meaning.

But you can make your layout more flexible.

the layout is more flexible, the less file is needed for screen various.

**You can use ConstraintLayout**

following is feature of ConstraintLayout.

1. can adjust position,size of views with proportion about other views.

for example, if you want to make a view charge 30% height of screen, you can make view like that.

also, you can put your view at 20% of screen height (0 = screen top, 100 = screen bottom)

2. can replace any other layout viewgroup(except CoordinatorLayout, MotionLayout...)
3. The same concept using constraint is used in iOS too. You can get better understanding in iOS later if you plan study it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on screen height, also I wasn't aware that a similar system could apply to iOS. However, when I talk of faster way to do it, I mean an option to avoid creating manually and one by one all the different sizes resolution layouts.